# Get previous month date to string no day

Tags: apex, date

New to salesforce and apex, was wondering if there was a good way to get a date in this format:

```
"201804"
```

would be what the function would return currently. Essentially the date last month without any days. I can think of hack jobs with substrings and such, but I was wondering if there was a nice proper apex way to get that sort of format?

Answer (score 1):

You can build it using Date methods that directly access the components of the Date value, assuming you have a Date instance:

```
String.valueOf(mydate.year()) + String.valueOf(myDate.month()).leftPad(2, '0');
```

You could also convert the Date to a DateTime and use its `format()` method, which takes a Java-style format string. You just have to be sure to use the GMT method variants to avoid time zone changes; since I find time zones bewildering, I prefer to just stick to accessing the Date directly.